# csv file generated in 000webhost is not downloading instead it is printing the result in the webpage. any solutions?

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

```
$file_name = 'data.csv';
```

headers

```
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
    header("Content-Type: application/csv;");
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $header = array("value");
    fputcsv($file, $header);
```

sql query

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE date >= '".$_POST["start_date"]."' AND date <= '".$_POST["end_date"]."' ORDER BY packet_id ASC";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $data = array();
        $data[] = $row["value"];   
        fputcsv($file, $data);
    }
    fclose($file);
    exit;
    }
```

this is working fine in localhost also i tried this in infinityfree.net in both the cases this code is working fine. i need to do this in 000webhost any solutions

i tried the .htaccess file modification and also analytics of 000webhost which says account not found.